# 看图说成语: What chengyu do these sketches refer to (from a grade-3 语文 textbook)?

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

This chengyu puzzle is on page 66 of a grade-3 语文 textbook (上册).

> [image: 语文 images]

I'm fairly sure I can get the top-left one, and the middle-right one, but not the others.

I present this as a chengyu puzzle (a relatively easy one).

**Question**: What chengyu do these sketches refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1 2`

`3 4`

`5 6`

> ```
> 1. 開門見山
> 2. 大材小用
> 3. 一舉兩得
> 4. 三長兩短
> 5. 小題大做
> 6. 百發百中
> ```